# Java Batch (JSR-352) - How to set a Job Parameter from a batchlet?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I have a batchlet that gets a file from a FTP server and stores it in a temporary folder. I would like to set the path of that folder as a batch job parameter, so that other steps can access the file. Is this possible and if so, how? My JSR 352 implementation is spring batch.

Edit: I am using Spring Batch 3.0 Milestone 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Minella I found out I could inject the JobContext in my Batchlet.

```
@Inject
private JobContext jobContext;
```

Now I can use this jobContext to set properties.

```
jobContext.setTransientUserData(myData);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in the location of the file as a job parameter using JSR-352's facilities as follows:

```
<step id="step1">
    <batchlet ref="fooBatchlet">
        <properties>
            <property name="fileName" value="#{jobParameters['testParam']}"/>
        </properties>
    </batchlet>
</step>
```

The above assumes you're using either the batch.xml or Spring DI to define fooBatchlet.  Otherwise, fooBatchlet would need to be the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This indeed injects the fileName into my batchlet. But my question was the other way around: set a (job/step) parameter from inside my batchlet. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah…no.  Parameters are one way in JSR-352.  The way to share that type of information within the JSR is using the `JobContext`'s transientData (assuming that you don't need it persisted for restart).  There isn't a way to store values within JSR-352 at a job level and make them available on restart (within Spring Batch, you can use the JobExecution's ExecutionContext for that functionality).

Comment: Thanks! Injecting the `JobContext` worked! I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spring are you using?

Assuming v3, you can store information to pass to other job steps either in the [StepContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/StepContext.html) or the JobExecutionContext. You can retrieve the StepContext from the ChunkContext which is passed into the BatchletAdapter RepeatStatus method.

Or you could set a JVM parameter, but that feels a bit clunky given that Spring offers the above methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using Spring batch 3.0 M3. I'll look into the BatchletAdapter, but I'd prefer to only use classes from the spec.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question…It can be done using spec specified configuration as shown in my answer below.